# skimage not opening thumbnail url

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

skimage is not able to load this thumbnail url, even though it is a valid url of an image. How to load the image?

```
from skimage import io

io.imshow(io.imread("http://www.moma.org/media/W1siZiIsIjMwMDQyMSJdLFsicCIsImNvbnZlcnQiLCItcmVzaXplIDMwMHgzMDBcdTAwM2UiXV0.jpg?sha=d98a16563c1c3b76"))

io.show()
```

Comment: This URL has an invalid SHA. That's the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a valid URL, the code works perfectly fine:

```
In [63]: from skimage import io    
In [64]: io.imshow(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUaSt.png'))
```

which shows the below image after correctly fetching it from the URL:

[image: img_loading]